# What is wrong with this mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation="upload/ . $_FILES["file"]["name"]" WHERE     
uid='$_SESSION[uid]'");
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the above code. Am I just not adding or subtracting quotations correctly somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are off.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "' WHERE uid='$_SESSION[uid]'");
```

Comment: thanks. now i just have to figure out why it isn't updating...

Comment: Noob question, but do i need to be doing more to make it execute (i.e. should it be updating just from this line of code?)

Comment: @GeorgePazdral - It is, but you shouldn't be using it. [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. That's unfortunate that it's deprecated...we've been coding our whole site with mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the quotes.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='upload/{$_FILES['file']['name']}' WHERE     
uid='{$_SESSION[uid]}'");
```

Comment: You're still missing the quotes.

Comment: My mistake. Corrected.